# Firefox redirecting to spoof ad sites (NOTE: this is not the usual Firefox redirect questio)

Tags: firefox, redirection, phishing

**Please read fully before downvoting or flagging as a possible duplicate!**

**This is not the standard Firefox redirect question—I've searched for some time and cannot find anything about this one.**

I recently started using the current Firefox (38.0.5), installing it on two machines, one at home and one in the office. The download was from the official site and was virus-scanned.

Within a few days, I had examples of the following on both machines.

If I entered a URL that would turn out to be unsuccessful (something offline etc), I would be taken to [a page masquerading as a BBC News article](http://bbc.com-iphone.eu/UK/LP117373_7545/indexp.html?voluumdata=vid..00000002-6280-4843-8000-000000000000__vpid..474b9000-17fc-11e5-8afb-00162c3130ec__caid..cda0f35f-5a9d-4ea7-9053-134e6723f506__rt..DJ__lid..1d574b24-68d3-478b-8487-52e4f0cd3809__oid1..ef245b4d-f29a-4be5-8c28-62983cd3903b__var1..india-cub-R36oUCUS__var2..what%20is%20a%20ip%20phone__var4..NON-ADULT__var5..DOMAIN__rd..) on how British citizens were flocking to get a brand new Samsung Galaxy or iPhone for only £1.00:

[image]

The page contains what seem to be phishing links (for example, a link to "official iPhone site" goes to "track.clicksbandit.com/click".

On both machines I had disabled searching from the address bar (which I detest!) so it seems this issue shouldn't have anything to do with searching invoked by Firefox.

When it happened on the office machine, I had not installed any add-ins.

What can be causing these malicious redirects?

Comment: Check for recently installed applications (`appwiz.cpl`) that you've never heard of. Some people have been infected by malware that's pretending to be a toolbar, search helper or security tool. This usually happens via drive-by downloads (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive-by_download) and be caused by outdated browser plugins such as Adobe's Flash Player or Java.

Comment: You should check that your DNS server settings were not changed, since these sometimes handle redirects in such situations.